# Spring-iBatis create database dynamically

Tags: spring

I am new to spring-iBatis. I have a requirement to create a database dynamically from my application. The database is MySql. I have seen that there are methods for insert,update and delete like SQLMap.insert(). but I am not finding any method to execute Create statement. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Abator](https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/tools/abator/) to assist in your code generation.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate can create a schema for you, because it takes information from objects and mappings and creates tables for you.

iBatis doesn't have the information about tables from mappings; you give it SQL to work with tables that are presumed to exist.

I'd recommend that you add SQL CREATE TABLE statements to a script and execute it with MySQL to create your schema.  It should be complete by the time you start with Java and iBatis.

Comment: Thank you duffymo for your quick reply. It was really helpful.